# C# Calculator typing by pressing buttons

Tags: c#, calculator

I am studying C# now, so i am making some kind of exercises to get used to C# syntax and learn better. I decided to make a calculator looking alike the normal windows calculator.

I created only one button "1" and one textbox.[image]

I want to make this button write 1 in textbox when I press it and also make an int variable equal to the number in the textbook, to make the calculation later. So I can't either change "int a"'s value or change text in the textbox, it always shows 01, because a always equals to 0.
How can I make the program, both show the correct numbers and change the value of a correctly? 
For example how can i make the program show eleven in the textbox when i press button twice and also change "int a"'s value to 11?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    int a;
    string Sa;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Sa = a.ToString() + "1";

        textBox1.Text = Sa;
    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Your question is not clear.  Do you know the difference between a string and an integer?  You do understand that a.ToString() + "1" is a string not an integer.  So it would simply concat a 1 to the string.

Comment: Append text before previous text  : textBox1.Text = "1" + textBox1.Text;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     textBox1.Text += "1";
}

private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    a = Int32.Parse(textBox1.Text);    
}
```

just it.. Change text on textBox every button click, and change variable a every textBox changed.

Answer (score 2):

The value could then be set using

```
a = int.Parse(Sa);
textBox1.Text = Sa.TrimStart('0');
```

Although if you'd like to be more efficient about it,

```
a = a * 10 + 1;
```

not have `Sa` at all,

```
textBox1.Text = a.ToString();
```

If you run into integer overflows, you should use [BigInteger](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CCAQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fsystem.numerics.biginteger.aspx&ei=8xX7Tp_DOIn30gGU-t2oAg&usg=AFQjCNGgfU2ditnOVPkrbp3_zHW6QlWXyQ&sig2=bC_1fSMw24A_SZLXGZIYUQ).

Answer (score 0):

You have several options:

Make int a nullable int. That way you can check if int is already set

```
int? a;

if ( a.HasValue )
{
}
else
{
}
```

Check if the Text property of textBox1 is empty (which means you don't have to append a to it)

```
if ( textBox1.Text == string.Empty)
{
}
else
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void btnOne_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtDisplay.Text = txtDisplay.Text + btnOne.Text;

        }

        private void btnTwo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtDisplay.Text = txtDisplay.Text + btnTwo.Text;
        }

// etc
```

Answer (score 0):

for any button you want to append text to the text box set the click property to `btn_Click` then pt this code inside the method

```
private void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = (Button)sender;
    // This will assign btn with the properties of the button clicked
    txt_display.Text = txt_display.Text + btn.Text;
    // this will append to the textbox with whatever text value the button holds
}
```