# C# read and calculate multiple values from textbox

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, calculator

I have a question about creating calculator in C# Windows Form Application. 
I want it to be possible write with form buttons an expression in textbox so for example **2+3+7=** and after pressing **"="** button program will read all digits and signs and perform calculation... I don't know from where to start and how could do it in such a way. Any help to any reference or smth to look at how to start doing such a expressions?

**Main thing is how to read, seperate and after calculate values from textbox.**

Thanks.

Comment: check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8656282/c-sharp-calculator-typing-by-pressing-buttons

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing You need to parse your expression into tokens, then apply order of math to it.
(2 + 3 + 7) * 4 => (5 + 7) * 4 => 12 * 4

Comment: I wrote a small library a while back to parse and evaluate arithmetic expressions. https://github.com/patriksvensson/arithmetica

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the Split method you could solve this rather easy.
Try this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  string[] parts = textBox1.Text.Split('+');
  int intSum = 0;
  foreach (string item in parts)
  {
    intSum = intSum + Convert.ToInt32(item);
  }
  textBox2.Text = intSum.ToString();
}
```

If you would like to have a more generic calculation, you should look at this post:
[In C# is there an eval function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6052640/in-c-sharp-is-there-an-eval-function)

Where this code snippet would do the thing:

```
public static double Evaluate(string expression)
{
  System.Data.DataTable table = new System.Data.DataTable();
  table.Columns.Add("expression", string.Empty.GetType(), expression);
  System.Data.DataRow row = table.NewRow();
  table.Rows.Add(row);
  return double.Parse((string)row["expression"]);
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  textBox2.Text = Evaluate(textBox1.Text).ToString();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, actually I had this Evaluate method found too. It works good, but I thought I need to write that calculation in different way for studies.. Thanks anyway :)